# Syntax of the case tactic in coq

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Can someone explain to me what the following coq tactic is doing?
case x : fun H => [|[]] // _.
How would I rewrite this using destruct?

Even better, can anyone point me to somewhere in the coq documentation where the above syntax is explained?

Comment: This does not look right.  There is a syntax error at the "fun" keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example given in the initial posting does not parse, so here is an attempt to produce a similar `case` command, but without the syntax error.

`case :` is part of the `ssreflect` idiom.  `case`  *name* `:` *value* `.` does approximately the same thing as `destruct`  *value* `eqn:` *name*.  The
`=>` is about making intro patterns in each case.

Here, I will explain the behavior of the following line:

```
case name : x H => [|[]] // _.
```

This does a destruct on `x` (we expect `x` to be in a type with two constructors, the second constructor having an argument which is itself in an inductive type; if `x` is in type `nat` this will work).

Now there is a subtlety from the fact that `H` appears between `x` and `=>`.  This means that the `H` hypothesis will be *reverted* to the conclusion of the
goal before the `case` command is performed.

```
revert H; destruct x as [ | [ | temporary_name]] eqn:name; try easy; intros _"
```

The `try easy` is here to represent the `//` used in the ssreflect idiom.
The `intros _` is here to represent the `_` present at the end of the ssreflect line: it gets rid of the corresponding instance of `H`  in the remaining case, probably because this contains a useless truth.

This explanation is not an exact match, because `case ... : ...` performs no
modifications in the goal hypotheses (except the one that was reverted), while `destruct` modifies any hypothesis where `x` occurs.

Here is an example of session where both tactics behave the same:

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.

Set Implicit Arguments.
Unset Strict Implicit.
Unset Printing Implicit Defensive.

Section sandbox.

Variable P : nat -> Prop.


Lemma toto (x : nat) (H : x == 1) : P x.
Proof.
revert H; destruct x as [| [| temporary]] eqn: name; try easy; intros _.
Abort.

Lemma titi (x : nat) (H : x == 1) : P x.
Proof.
case name : x H => [|[]] // _.
Abort.
```